# Top Questions of the Week #3

Tags: discussion, status-completed, question-of-the-week, superuser-blog, top-questions

Now we're into week 3 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://superuser.blogoverflow.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each we week we are going to try to post about the question and it's contents.

Comment: I notice that the [question-of-the-week] tag is missing from this, but I don't have enough rep to tag it, could someone do it?

Comment: Fixed @Fábio! Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 9):

[Best way to get data off a computer with no support for USB or ethernet](https://superuser.com/questions/237198/best-way-to-get-data-off-a-computer-with-no-support-for-usb-or-ethernet)

> A customer has a computer running Windows 98 (I know, cringe) and needs to take some data off the computer to put on a new laptop.
>
> I've tried using USB, but Windows 98 doesn't have USB storage drivers. So I thought I'd transfer the data via ethernet, but the computer doesn't have an ethernet port...
>
> I then decided to try and burn the data to a CD, but we only had blank DVDs on hand. And of course, the drive doesn't write to DVDs.

Comment: Any 'unexpected' solutions?

Comment: tbh no, @IvoFlipse

Answer (score 3):

With us starting to test the SSD tech this may be a good start.

[Are SSD's really reliable enough for power users?](https://superuser.com/questions/238135/are-ssds-really-reliable-enough-for-power-users)

> About 9 months ago I bought an SSD, an OCZ Vertex Turbo (60GB). Up until about 2 weeks ago, I really loved the drive. It was extremely reliable and it really does make your system much more responsive. But 2 weeks ago, the drive started failing. It took me about 1 1/2 weeks just to pinpoint the exact problem, and the last 1/2 a week it just got progressively worse. The drive has been taking back to the shop.

Answer (score 3):

Nobody said it couldn't be a Meta question!

[**What do you want Super User Blog to test with SSD technology?**](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1996/what-do-you-want-super-user-blog-to-test-with-ssd-technology)

> In conjunction with the Super User blog, we will be getting at least one, maybe more, SSD's from Kingston. We want to perform tests on these drives and blog about the results, and need your help. What testing, comparisons, or how to guides, would you as a Super User like to see related to SSD technology?

My idea would be to blog about all the suggestions as a sort of announcement and to make sure Kronos can prepare himself for the testing. Additionally we can add some information from other SSD questions we have on SU.